# Sentence with demonstrative without explicit subject - de required?

Tags: grammar, particles, adjectives

I am unable to understand, whether the sentences below require the particle de?

> **Zhè ge hěn hào chī** (literally "this piece of food delicious". I guess there is no "de" in the end, although it is an adjective in this sentence, modifying the measure word "ge").
>
> **zhè zhī hēi de** (This cat is black. For some reason, there is the "de" but I cannot see why).
>
> **zhè Ben Shu hěn hào** (This book is good. Here again, the "de" is missing. When I tried to verify with google translate, it used 是 but I guess that is not correct.)

So is it because those are one-syllable adjectives? I have heard that often in that case, the "de" particle is skipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always check the full context of your original sentence. 的 use to indicate items/things/action explicitly.

```
你说的是那一只猫 ？ ： Which cat your are talking about
zhè zhī hēi de 这只黑的 ：This black one (pointing to specific black cat among many black cats)
你要那一支蓝笔 ？ ： Which blue pen you need? 
这支蓝的,(or simply 这支) ： This one , for specific. (or simply "This one")
```

What happens when you say : 
 zhè zhī hēi  这只黑

This always follow after an inquiry for comparative items, with affirmative answer.

```
Q ：I want the darkest black cat 我要最黑的黑猫
A : This is the darkest(or simply, "this one")   这只黑 (这只）
Q : Give me the sweetest watermelon 我要最甜的西瓜
A : This one 这个甜
```

Comment: Actually, in Zhè ge hěn hào chī, is "hao chi" adjective? So is it relating to the "ge"?

Comment: @Roudak :  "ge" is a classifier.  So "hao chi" related to "Zhè" (this)

Answer (score 7):

> 这个很好吃。

一般语气，可以不加'的'。
若要加强语气，加'的'，而且念重一点。

> 这是黒的。
>   这猫是黒色的。

通常要加'的'。

> 这本书很好。

和第一例一様，平常可省略；加强语气时，加'的'。

Answer (score 1):

1. 有时候会在形容词后面加“的”，没什么实际意义。

比如：

诶，我和你讲，这瓜超甜的。

（Hey, I'd like to tell you that this melon is so sweet.）

2. 有时候“的”的后面省略了一些词，需要根据语境（context）补充。

比如：

```
这支笔是谁的？（谁的笔）

我的（我的笔）
```

٩( 'ω' )و May you understand what I said.